# Solving algebra with multiple square root

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, radicals

I am currently solving an algebra and can't figure it out, could anyone help me on this?

$$2\sqrt{N + \sqrt{N^2+4c^2}} = \sqrt{N + \sqrt{N^2+3c^2}} + \sqrt{N + \sqrt{N^2+5c^2}}$$

Which I would like to have a solution to represent N in terms of c, or c in terms of N, either way works. If this is unsolvable, please show me the reason for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have values  for the variable $c$ ?

Comment: The solution of Maple is a polynomial of degree 64!

Comment: hey Dr! both N and c are positive integers! So does that mean this is unsolvable?

Comment: It is solvable, but i think no per hand!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ok...so could u show me some possible approaches?

Comment: Sorry i need a night to think about this problem!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ohh god,I got u, thanks for that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $c=0$ is a solution.  But there are no other real solutions.

After noting that $N=0$ is impossible, we divide both sides by $\sqrt{N}$ and let $c^2/N^2 = t$ to get
$$ 2 \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1 + 4 t}} = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+3t}} + \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+5t}} $$
We can write this as 
$$ 2 g(4 t) = g(3 t) + g(5 t) $$
where 
$$ g(x) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}$$
Now this function is strictly concave for $x > 0$, as we see by taking its second derivative.  Thus since $4 = (3+5)/2$, $g(4t) > (g(3t) + g(5t))/2$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: That is very clear and fast. Thanks a lot!